# OpenCV - Appending contours inside ROI as numpy array in python

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy

In the picture below I have found and drawn the contour(green) of my object. I would like to get the contour coordinates as a numpy array, so I have used
 `array = np.vstack(contours).squeeze()`. This gives me the coordinates of the entire contour in an array.

**My question: is it possible to append only the contour coordinates(two green lines) inside the ROI(red square) into an array**?

I know I can find contour inside a ROI separately, but I'm interested in doing it this way since the plan is to have several ROIs, and I dont want to find contours seperatly for each ROI. Any help is much appreciated.

**Image with the contour**

[image: Image with contour]

**Original picture:**

[image: original picture]

Here is the code if anyone is interested:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, 0)
inv = 255 - thresh

im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(inv, cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 2)
array = np.vstack(contours).squeeze()

x, y, w, h= 150, 50, 500 ,150
roi = img[y:(y+h),x:(x+w)]
cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0,0,255), 1)

cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: For every coordinate of the green contour, check whether the `x` is **greater** than `x` of the square and **lesser** than `x + w` of the square. Likewise, check whether the `y` is **greater** than `y` of the square and **lesser** than `y + h` of the square. Hope you understand....

Comment: That was an easy and fast way to do it, thank you so much! I have a quick follow up, do you have a good idea how to seperate the green line coordinates into two seperate arrays? Thanks again :)

Comment: WOW That actually worked Splendid!! It just came off the top of my head!!!.. Two separate arrays meaning, green line on left into one array and the green line on right into another array?

Comment: yes excactely :)

Comment: performing **adaptive threshold** will get you those two lines separately. Then you can find those points and put them in two different arrays